# Populating UITableView with timeout

Tags: swift

I am creating chatbot application, which imitates real user "typing" status, so after each message there must be 1 second (for example) delay, before application will post second message.

My messaging logic is

```
    let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
    let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
    let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];

    for row in part {
        if let message = row as? Message {
            self.sendMessage(message: message);
            print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
            usleep(1 * 1000 * 1000)
        }

        if let question = row as? Question {

        }
    }
```

here i am taking random array of Messages (actually strings), and in a loop just adding them to my table, like this

```
func sendMessage(message: Message) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates();

    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.log.count, section: 0);
    self.log.insert(
        message,
        at: self.log.count
    );
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade);
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

problem is, that if there is 10 strings in an array of messages, i see 10 "MESSAGE TRIGGERED" logs in a console, 1 new row, each second, like i planned, but in a table, i don't see any rows for 10 second, and then they all just appears at once. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running on the main thread and never giving the system the chance to update the table.  You violated the rule: **never call `sleep` on the main thread**.

You can fix this several ways:

1) Run your loop on a background thread, and return to the main thread to call `self.sendMessage` and `print`.

```
let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    for row in part {
        if let message = row as? Message {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sendMessage(message: message);
                print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
            }
            usleep(1 * 1000 * 1000)
        }

        if let question = row as? Question {

        }
    }
}
```

2) Use a repeating timer with an interval of `1` second and add one item to your table each time the timer fires.

```
let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];

var idx = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in

    if idx >= part.count {
        timer.invalidate()
    } else {
        let row = part[idx]
        if let message = row as? Message {
            self.sendMessage(message: message);
            print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
        }

        if let question = row as? Question {

        }
    }
    idx += 1
}
```

3) Delay each table addition by an increasingly larger delay:

```
let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];

var delay = 0.0
for row in part {
    if let message = row as? Message {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            self.sendMessage(message: message);
            print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
        }
        delay += 1.0
    }

    if let question = row as? Question {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your this code by:

```
let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];

for row in part {
    if let message = row as? Message {
        self.sendMessage(message: message);
        print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
        usleep(1 * 1000 * 1000)
    }

    if let question = row as? Question {

    }
}
```

this code:

```
let size = dictionary[key]!.count;
let pointer = random(lower: 0, upper: UInt32(size) - 1);
let part = dictionary[key]![pointer];
var timer = Timer!
for row in part {
    if let message = row as? Message {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    if let question = row as? Question {

    }
}
timer.invalidate()
```

also add this function:

```
  @objc func runTimedCode() {
      self.sendMessage(message: message);
        print("MESSAGE TRIGGERED");
  }
```

Comment: Works fine, but triggers not a single row each 10 seconds, but all rows each 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but found a problem, your code triggers 10 intervals at once, all with same delay of 1 second, so they all "timeouts" at same time, i just changed timeInterval for +1 second for each next message row, and they now timeouts with 1 second from the previous row :)

Comment: with small fixes - yes

Comment: please feel free to edit my answer and please accept the answer if its useful so that it will help other people to find the correct answer for their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do not sleep main thread.

Instead, you set a function call a second after.

You should create a timer inside every cell, then every cell have seperate timers.

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak private var myLabel: UILabel!

private var timer: Timer?
private var timeCounter: Double = 0

var expiryTimeInterval: TimeInterval? {
    didSet {
        startTimer()
    }
}

private func startTimer() {
    if let interval = expiryTimeInterval {
        timeCounter = interval // should be 1 for 1 second.
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                          repeats: true,
                          block: { [weak self] _ in
                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                return
                            }
                            strongSelf.onComplete()
            })
        } else {
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                          target: self,
                          selector: #selector(onComplete),
                          userInfo: nil,
                          repeats: true)
        }
    }
}

@objc func onComplete() {
    guard timeCounter >= 0 else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        return
    }
    myLabel.text = String(format: "%d", timeCounter)
    timeCounter -= 1
}
}
```

And you can use like this ;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCustomCell

    cell.expiryTimeInterval = 10

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but triggers not a single row each 10 seconds, but all rows each 10 seconds.

Comment: Found a problem, your code triggers 10 intervals at once, all with same delay of 1 second, so they all "timeouts" at same time, so i just changed timeInterval for +1 second for each next message row, and they now timeouts with 1 second difference :)

Comment: Ok, how about now? I changed answer to fix your issue.